# error 1064: Update a table with a column and a number in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to `update` a table with `2` values, one of them is a column of another table and the second is a number (`constant 1`), here is my code:

```
insert into table (col1, col2)
select colA from table2, '1' 
 where DATA_FORMAT(table2.created_at, '%y %m %d') = DATA_FORMAT(Now(), '%y %m %d');
```

The error message is:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0', '1', '1'  where DATA_FORMAT(newsletter.created_at, '%y %m %d') = DATA_FORMA' at line 2
```

Comment: I think you meant `DATE_FORMAT()`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
insert into table (col1, col2)
select colA, '1' as ColB from table2
where DATE_FORMAT(table2.created_at, '%y %m %d') = DATE_FORMAT(Now(), '%y %m %d');
```

Comment: Didn't work. This is actually the query I'm using:
insert into crm_users (email, category, quantidade, ativo)
select newsletter.email from newsletter, '0' as qtd, '1' as atv, '1' 
where DATA_FORMAT(newsletter.created_at, '%y %m %d') = DATA_FORMAT(Now(), '%y %m %d');